# How to get difference values between 2 tables in pandas?

Tags: pandas

For example I have 2 dataframes: one with 693407 and another 829768 rows. This dataframes have a similar number of columns. Total difference between 2 tables is 136361. How can I get those values that fall in to difference of 136361?

Comment: How do you recognize if a row is repeated or a new row? You'll need to be more specific.

Comment: By unique ID. Both tables do not have duplicates IDs.